# I want to implement the floating window in the html

Tags: html, css

I want to implement the floating window in the html which it has scroll down when i am scrolling the page down

Comment: what do you mean scroll down when you scroll down. Do you mean just the ability to scroll the floated div or do you want it to scroll when you scroll the browser?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give your window element `position: fixed;` in the CSS.  Position it with `left`, `right`, `top`, and/or `bottom`.  See [CSS2 positioning schemes on W3.org](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#positioning-scheme).

Comment: Also have a look at the (slightly) more friendly reference on Sitepoint.com: http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/position